# How to send mail when error after all tests completed

Tags: phpunit

```
class Listener extends PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to run `phpunit` two times a day, and when errors detected, send the log email to me, all I can find is use [Listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener), but I can't find events like `endAllTest`, `endTest` and `endTestSuite` event will run at each suite or test was finished, I need to do something after **all tests finished** and **errors be detected**, how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want a test runner. Have a look at Travis CI.

Comment: PHPUnit will return an ErrorLevel as well if run from the command line, so you use batch files, powershell, etc... to branch and send an email.